# 2 lines intersecting at the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

How can I draw these colored pictures in Latex?

> [image]

I am not caring about the thickness of the coloured lines in both pictures, ordinary thickness is fine. Also the letter below the first figure is $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can speak:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[green] (240:1) -- (60:1); 
\draw[cyan] (-60:1) -- (120:1);
\draw[] (0:1) -- (180:1);
\fill[cyan] (0,0) circle(0.3);
\fill[green] (0,0) circle(0.2);
\fill[purple] (0,0) circle(0.1);
\node[] at (0.3,-1) {$\mathbb{G}_m$};
\node[] at (1.5,0.5) {$\mathbb{A}^2\backslash \{0\}$};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\draw[cyan] (45:1) -- (225:1);
\draw[cyan] (135:1) -- (315:1);
\draw[] (0:1) -- (180:1);
\draw[] (90:1) -- (270:1);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle(0.15);
\node[] at (1.5,0.5){$\mathbb{A}^2\backslash \{0\}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what if I want to make the circles on the left thin also?

Comment: edit ```\fill[] circle(xxx);```